# Resize Bootstrap 4 grid when below certain width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I have a simple Bootstrap 4 grid layout that I would like to make responsive so it can work on tablet and mobiles also. Sadly I have not much experience with responsive design and view-ports but I have now come up with a very basic container layout like this.

I have this:

[image: Bootstrap 4 layout]

This works fine on desktops but I would also like to support smaller devices so when resizing below a certain point then ideally it should reformat the layout. For example I could hide the `Logo` and `Timeline` box and then resize the `Banner` to be 12 columns and the width of the page to be `975px`.

But how!? ;-)

What if I want this:

[image: I want this]

I do have this CSS that will hide the two DIVs if the page comes below 1300px:

```
@media all and (max-width: 1300px) {
    .logo {
        display: none;
    }
    .timeline {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

I do have this JSFiddle for it, https://jsfiddle.net/wmt74sfd/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Bootstrap 4 [display utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/) and [auto-layout columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#setting-one-column-width).

Use `d-none d-xl-block` to hide the `.logo` on widths < 1200px. Use `col` instead of `col-10` on the adjacent column so that auto resizes to full-width when the `logo` col-2 is hidden. The same works for the `timeline`.

```
<div class="container page">
  <!-- Logo + Banner -->
  <div class="row">

    <!-- Logo -->
    <div class="col-2 logo d-none d-xl-block">
      <p><strong>Logo</strong></p>
      <p>Div: <span id="logoWidth"></span>px</p>
    </div>

    <!-- Banner -->
    <div class="col banner">
      <p><strong>Banner</strong></p>
      <p>Div: <span id="bannerWidth"></span>px</p>
    </div>
  </div>

    <!-- Menu + Content + Timeline -->
  <div class="row">

        <!-- Menu -->
    <div class="col-2 menu">
      <p><strong>Menu</strong></p>
      <p>Div: <span id="menuWidth"></span>px</p>
    </div>

        <!-- Content -->
    <div class="col content">
      <p><strong>Content</strong></p>
      <p>Monitor: <span id="screenWidth"></span>x<span id="screenHeight"></span>px</p>
      <p>Browser: <span id="screenAvailWidth"></span>x<span id="screenAvailHeight"></span>px</p>
      <p>Div: <span id="contentWidth"></span>px</p>
    </div>

        <!-- Timeline -->
    <div class="col-3 timeline d-none d-xl-block">
      <p><strong>Timeline</strong></p>
      <p>Div: <span id="timelineWidth"></span>px</p>
    </div>
  </div>

    <!-- Footer -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 footer">
      <p><strong>Footer</strong></p>
      <p>Div: <span id="footerWidth"></span>px</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/RuHXXyTBJd

If you want it to be exactly at 1300px, keep the @media query, and the adjacent `col` will resize to full-width when the logo or timeline is hidden. Also, I don't think you want to set a min-width on the `.page` as will make it not responsive.

Comment: I do now get the meaning of `col` and `d-none d-xl-block`, thanks. However I will need the specific widths as the `Menu`, `Content` and `Timeline` always should have the width as content otherwise will not match too well. E.g. the `Menu` should be aprox 200-225px, the `Content` should be 700-800px and the `Timeline` should be 275-350px. Do you have any idea how to do that if not setting `min-width` in `@media``?